# Internet connection drops every 10 seconds on Macbook Pro (M1 Pro)

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, internet, ventura

So, a recent issue with my Macbook Pro w/ M1 Pro running macOS Ventura beta is that it keeps dropping its internet connection *exactly* every 10 seconds.

Regardless of whether I'm using ethernet, work or home wi-fi, or even my cellphone's hotspot.

For example, results of ping:

```
PING google.com (142.251.32.206): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=9.467 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=11.747 ms
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=9.934 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=10.050 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=9 ttl=52 time=13.127 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=10 ttl=52 time=11.709 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=11 ttl=52 time=10.346 ms
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 12
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 14
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 15
Request timeout for icmp_seq 16
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=17 ttl=52 time=11.902 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=18 ttl=52 time=10.025 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=19 ttl=52 time=10.130 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=20 ttl=52 time=10.546 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=21 ttl=52 time=9.967 ms
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 23
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 24
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 25
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 26
Request timeout for icmp_seq 27
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=28 ttl=52 time=9.903 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=29 ttl=52 time=9.885 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=30 ttl=52 time=9.557 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.32.206: icmp_seq=31 ttl=52 time=9.982 ms
```

I've tried:

- turning wifi off and on
- restarting
- renewing DHCP lease
- deleting wifi or ethernet service in Settings -> Network and re-adding
- using different DNS servers like 1.1.1.1 instead of the default

The fact that it happens on either wifi or ethernet, whether at work or at home suggests it isn't a router problem.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1:** Per Allan’s suggestion in the comments, I restarted into Recovery mode and used the Terminal there to ping google again, and there are no drops every 10 seconds. But logging back into non-Recovery mode, the problem remains ;_;

Comment: Instead of pining something outside your network (like Google), start by pinging something inside your network like the router or another device.  This will begin to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Allan Same issue inside the network too - drops every 10 seconds.

Comment: What did you ping?  What were the results?  Can you post like you did Google’s ping results?

Comment: I can't post the results with my work IP address listed (my external and internal IPs are the same), but I pinged a neighboring computer that's on the same subnet (ie pinged `a.b.c.d` from `a.b.c.e`). I've also done this at home, with 192.168.1.x but don't have the text to copy/paste. Same result, with "No route to host" and "Request timeout" exactly every 10 seconds.

Comment: The IPs at work are similar to home in that they are private addresses and used by many other orgs.  You can still obfuscate if necessary. Do you have VPN software, custom DNS entries?  Do you have WiFi and Ethernet active at the same time?  If so, disable and focus on Ethernet first.

Comment: I've removed the custom DNS entries I had attempted (1.1.1.1) so no custom DNS; I've uninstalled my work VPN software (no longer shows up under Settings -> Network -> Filters); and I've tried wifi and ethernet separately by deleting the other service (by Ctrl-clicking on the network in Settings -> Network). The drop-every-10-seconds issue remains whether I'm on wifi-only, or ethernet-only.

Comment: Boot into Safe or Recovery.  If Recovery, when there, open Terminal (Utilities menu)  and try pinging again.

Comment: Interesting - in Recovery mode’s Terminal I don’t see any drops in the Ethernet connection when pinging a local computer or something outside the network. Good idea!

Comment: This means a 3rd party app or kext is at fault here.  You might want to do a full backup, then a clean install (on external drive for now) and install things one-by-one.  Something got installed that’s interfering with your network stack.

Comment: @Allan Thank you for your Recovery mode clue! It turns out it's my work's Cisco AMP for Endpoints MaLwARE ProtECTioN service, which also adds a content filter to Settings -> Network -> Filters. I disabled that filter as well and quit Amp, and the network no longer drops every 10 seconds! Turns out it's actually a bug with content filters in the latest version of Ventura: https://www.macrumors.com/2023/05/02/macos-ventura-13-4-content-filter-issue/

How do I mark this as solved if there are no "Answers"? Feel free to post your Recovery mode comment as an answer and I'll accept that!

Comment: Recovery was just the diagnostic as it loads a completely clean version of macOS which would positively eliminate any 3rd party “contaminants”.  Go ahead and self answer, then ping me here so I can up vote for you. After all, you did the investigative work and found the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Special thanks to @Allan in the question comments for the boot-into-Recovery-mode tip which helped me diagnose this issue.

It turns out it's Cisco's AMP for Endpoints MaLwARE ProtECTioN service, which also adds a content filter to Settings -> Network -> Filters. I disabled that filter as well and quit Amp, and the network no longer drops every 10 seconds!

Apparently there's a bug with content filters in the latest version of Ventura beta: https://www.macrumors.com/2023/05/02/macos-ventura-13-4-content-filter-issue/

So, if you're on macOS Ventura 16.4 Beta (22F5059b) and running into this network-drops-every-10-seconds issue, you'll have to **disable or delete all your content filters** in Settings -> Network -> Filters while Apple fixes the issue (hopefully soon).

**Edit on 2023/05/10:** Looks like the newest Ventura update (22F62) has now fixed this issue, so no need to delete or disable your content filters!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: The 13.4 release candidate has a fix for this, I think.

Comment: @benwiggy Yup, just updated to 13.4 RC (22F62) and the content-filters-breaking-network problem is fixed! This question was only relevant for a week lol.